# Unit Testing a mock WCF client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, mocking, nunit

I'm having serious issues in how to deploy a WCF client in a MVC site which is easily testable. I'm struggling to set up a mock of the service without actually accessing a endpoint.

Example Controller of site under test

```
public class ProfileController : ControllerExtended
{

    public ProfileController(IUserService membershipService, IDropDownService dropdownService, ISiteService siteService)
    {
        WCFService.Instance.Client = siteService; //Should maybe be a serpate service.
        _membershipService = membershipService;
        _dropDownService = dropdownService;
        _siteService = siteService;

    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        UserComp profile = _siteService.ProfileGet(_sharedContext.CurrentUser.id);

        return View(new ProfileViewModel { Profile = profile });
    }
}
```

WCF Singleton (I think my implementation of WCF is my issue, should it be in a interface?)

```
public sealed class WCFService
{

    public SiteServiceI Client { get; set; }

    #region Singleton

    static readonly WCFService query = new WCFService();

    static WCFService()
    {
    }

    WCFService()
    {
    }

    public static WCFService Instance
    {
        get { return query; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

UnitTest

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private Mock<SiteService> mockSiteService;
    private Mock<IUserService> mockMembershipService;
    private Mock<IDropDownService> mockDropDown;
    private Mock<SiteServiceIClient> mockServiceClient; //new Mock<SiteServiceIClient>();


    //private Mock<WebService> mockWebService;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        mockSiteService = new Mock<ISiteService>();
        mockMembershipService = new Mock<IUserService>();
        mockDropDown = new Mock<IDropDownService>();
        mockServiceClient = new Mock<SiteServiceIClient>();

        mockWebService = new Mock<WebService>(mockServiceClient);
    }

    [Test]
    public void CheckHomeIndex_Controller()
    {

        var controller = new HomeController(mockMembershipService.Object, mockDropDown.Object, mockPTSearch.Object, mockServiceClient.Object); // mockServiceClient times out.

        Assert.AreEqual("this", "this");
    }
}
```

I assume the errors are occurring because the singleton sets the service up as soon as it is initialised. I've tried to implement a separate service purely for called to WCF but not had success in implementing it in a testable manner. Not too sure if this is to vague but I've read a lot on it and not an closer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The singleton is definitely your problem - testing with singletons is entering a world of pain. You should implement a [facade](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFacade.aspx) pattern to make this testing friendly. Something like this:

```
public interface IServiceFacade
{
    Profile ProfileGet(int id);
}

public class ServiceFacade : IServiceFacade
{

    private WCFService _theRealService = new WCFService();

    public Profile ProfileGet(int id)
    {
        return _theRealService.ProfileGet(id);
    }
}



public class Some_Tests()
{
    public void Test_Stuff_Whatever()
    {

        Mock<IServiceFacade> _facade = new Mock<IServiceFacade>();

        _facade.SetUp(Whatever.....);
    }
}
```

Comment: So this way I basically need to add replica local copy of the whole WCF interface? Thanks, I'll get on and try that!

Comment: @Oli - yes but no, you implement a "local copy" in the interface you create, but only expose from that interface the operations from the WCF service that are interesting to you and your application.

Comment: Currently this is the first application accessing the service so it is one on one there for they will be identical but thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your service is singleton. The problem of singleton pattern is that it is not testable. You should use Dependency injection to get service.

Comment: What would be a more test friendly approach?